# MinGW windres.exe resource compiler syntax error

Tags: winapi

I'm trying to compile a resource file (.rc) for a Win32 application but I'm getting this error

```
use "" to put " in a string
```

Among other things, I'm trying to define a `MENUITEM` with a string that looks like this `"&Save\t\"Alt+S\""`. I have tried escaping the `"` character with `"\""` but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you escaping it with `\"` when the resource compiler clearly says you that you must escape it with `""`? Just do:

```
"&Save\t""Alt+S"""
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that i tried that too.The program was compiled with borland's bcc32 compiler and it's resource compiler brcc32 didn't signal no such error.Of course that's not the point but it doesn't work.If you have more suggestions i would be happy to put them in practice.

Comment: @MariusPirvu: glad you solved, you could post your solution as an answer and auto-accept it, it will be useful to future visitors! :)